# Using winapi, how do I make to processes (one x86, the other x64) communicate via a Memory Mapped File?

Tags: c++, winapi, x86, 64-bit, shared-memory

I have two processes. One of them is a 32-bit process, the other is x64.

I make them communicate via a Memory Mapped File (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Communication has worked ok so far, but recently I've added another member to the structure and some problems have arisen.

The member I've added is a std::vector < Test > (where Test is a user defined structure which has 3 strings and a bool).

Whenever I try to read the structure from the 32 bit process, the old members are read successfully, but the new member (the vector) is read but is empty.

I found out the problem is due to the fact that the size of my structure is no longer the same on both architectures and thus the 32-bit process doesn't read the whole vector.

Any idea how I can solve this? Easy fix for this or a better approach? (although I'd prefer a fix for this as a different approach would require a lot of refactoring)

Comment: It ain't gonna fly. Basically, `std::vector` holds a pointer to the actual data. It's that pointer that you write to shared memory, not the data itself. The pointer to memory in one process is of course useless to the other process (even if you manage to communicate it successfully). You can't use `vector` (or anything smart) - you need to flatten actual data into the shared memory.

Comment: Data memory layout is fundamental to understanding 64-bit versus 32-bit. When you don't understand that, and you didn't when you tried the vector stunt, trying to communicate via a memory mapped file is not the first thing to try. It's, like, the last thing.

Comment: OK, I've seen the error of my ways. Any suggestions on a better approach?

Comment: COM can bridge the gap between 64-bit and 32-bit.

Comment: The communication will use serialization and de-serialization in one way or another. COM provides `IStream` which is the de-facto standard to marshal data between arbitrary processes. Or you could implement something else altogether, e.g. JSON-serialized data communicated through named pipes. Whichever way you choose, it remains an exercise in serialization.

Comment: You can solve the 64-bit vs 32-bit size problem (which is a serialization problem in a way) by carefully choosing your data types. Use plain-old-data (POD), i.e., structs and arrays without pointers and you should be good.

Comment: Memory mapped files work fine between 32 and 64 bit processes. The problem is that you didn't serialize the data. As Alf says this is absolutely the last form of IPC that you would ever consider.